# laravel testing with faker big text

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit, faker

I'm testing a form where user must introduce some text between let's say 100 and 500 characters.

I tried to emulate the user input:

```
$this->actingAs($user)
->visit('myweb/create')
->type($this->faker->text(1000),'description')
->press('Save')
->see('greater than');
```

But it seems that faker is creating a quite smaller text so the test does not pass.

In fact, the param specifies the max number of characters, not the minimum. How can I tell faker the minimum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Faker API does not provide you with an option to set the minimum number of characters. So you better use something else, for example Laravel's `str_random(1000)` helper function will create a string consisting of exactly 1000 characters.

Comment: Thanks, I was going with `faker->words(500)` :)

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question when having the same problem.

1. `str_random()` As answered is an undefined function now. In L11 use the string helper `Str::random($length)`, like in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/strings#method-str-random).
2. `faker->words(500)` Will generate an array containing a specified amount of random words, and optionally, a second boolean parameter can be supplied. When `true`, a string will be returned instead of an array. You can check the docs [here](https://fakerphp.github.io/formatters/text-and-paragraphs/). So:

```
faker->words(500)
// ['word1', 'word2', 'word3', ...]
```

and

```
faker->words(500, true)
// 'word1 word2 word3 ...'
```

.: The `words()` will generate `500` words with `N` chars.

3. Use `lexify`, if you want the **exact number of chars**. This will generate a string where all `?` characters are replaced with a random letter from the Latin alphabet. here is the [docs](https://fakerphp.github.io/formatters/numbers-and-strings/#lexify). So:

```
faker->lexify(str_repeat('?', 500))
// 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz...'
```

4. To achieve what you really want, you have the `realTextBetween()`. This will generate a text **between** 2 numbers. Here are the [docs](https://fakerphp.github.io/formatters/#fakerprovideren_ustext). So:

```
realTextBetween($minNbChars = 160, $maxNbChars = 200, $indexSize = 2)
// "VERY short remarks:, and she ran across the garden, and I had not long to doubt, for the end of the bottle was NOT marked 'poison,' it is right?' --'In my youth,' Father William replied to his ear."
```

.: Be aware that there are added non-alphanumeric characters like symbols, punctuation, or other special characters such as `, : - ' ? .` etc..